# C++ Creating a Screen Saver for Windows

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, sdl

I have created an animation in C++ using OpenGL and SDL (it uses no Windows libraries) and wish to use it as a screen saver for a Windows system. I read one example: it describes that you simply have to change the `.exe` extension to `.scr`.

I have done that and ran the animation as a screen saver but I noticed that the animation did **not** run smoothly at all. As if there was a loss in the application performance.

The application I made creates the animation, sets it to full screen, hides the cursor and handles all keyboard input. How can I make my application run smoothly as a screen saver?

Comment: probably with DirectX it works better. Is the exe file performance as you wish?

Comment: The exe file works perfect. when I change it to scr it loses performance. Is this a common issue when changing the extension?

Comment: I'm not sure. It seems Windows treats scr otherwise. Try to change native windows screensavers to exe files and compare there performancea.

Comment: [this](http://www.wischik.com/scr/holsavers.html) explains how to write a screen saver. May help.

Comment: Windows sets the task priority of screen savers below normal. SO it makes sense that your screen saver receives less CPU time if not run normally.

Comment: BTW, being pedantic, your application *does* use Windows libraries -- under the hood the SDL implementation on Windows is using the Windows standard API. If you looked at import dependencies (e.g. with Dependency Walker) you'll see all the other libraries it uses.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's more than just renaming the file.

At the bare minimum you must support correct behavior in response to the following command line parameters (taken from [Microsoft](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/182383/en-us)):

```
ScreenSaver           - Show the Settings dialog box.
ScreenSaver /c        - Show the Settings dialog box, modal to the
                        foreground window.
ScreenSaver /p <HWND> - Preview Screen Saver as child of window <HWND>.
ScreenSaver /s        - Run the Screen Saver.
```

If multiple instances of your executable are being started and run as a full screen screen saver (the screen saver should only actually run if /s is specified), that may be the cause of your performance issues. You should verify that in e.g. Task Manager.

Hope that helps.

Comment: In order to make the screen saver I would have to make a Win32 project? Since I used SDL, I need the main function since without it it claims an undefined reference to `SDL_main`.

Comment: Yes, make a Windows application project, and just use main() instead of WinMain(). See "creating a project with SDL" at http://www.libsdl.org/tmp/SDL/VisualC.html .

Comment: Well it has already been a while since I finished my working screen saver. I made it into a Win32 project using only OpenGL with proper support. My animation simply rotates an image continuously but the screen saver but does not run smoothly when rotating large images(800 X 800) so I have to scale it down to around (200 x 200).

Comment: How are you rotating the image? You should be able to rotate an 800x800 image smoothly by using the image as a texture, rendered to a single quad, and rotate the quad.

Comment: Yes it is a textured. I am using matrix transformations to do the rotation and translations. I followed the lazy foo tutorials to create a texture. The image rotates nicely as a .exe but not as a .scr

Comment: Does your application rely on any OpenGL DLLs that may be not be in your system path? Just out of curiosity, call glGetString(GL_VENDOR) in both your exe and scr versions, log the string it returns, and make sure you are using the hardware renderer in both cases.