# How do I start a .scr file from CMD?

Tags: cmd, command-line, command-line-arguments, screensaver, windows-screensaver

I want to start "Bubbles.scr" from CMD which is located in C:\Windows\System32\

But it tells me it has no options that I can set.
How do I launch it?

[image]

Comment: did you tried with `bubbles.src /s` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/ms686421(v=vs.85)#command-line-options https://stackoverflow.com/a/18050561/7370767

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
bubbles.scr /s
```

It can also be called directly from powershell without any options